# Does A linear Transformation Of This Kind Exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is there a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}_2[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$

So that

$Ker(T)=span \{ 1+x-x^2, 2+3x^2 \}$

$Im(T)=span \{ (0,0,9) \}$

What I have done:

$Ker(T)=(\alpha+\alpha x+\alpha x^2+2\beta+3\beta x^2)=(\alpha+2\beta)+\alpha x+(3\beta-\alpha)x^2$

by definition the expression $(\alpha+2\beta)+\alpha x+(3\beta-\alpha)x^2=0$
and it can be only if $\alpha=\beta=0$ therefore $Ker(T)={0}$ and $Dim(Ker(T))=0$.

By $DimV=DimKer(T)+DimIm(T)$ the dimension of Im(T) is  3=0+Im(T) but Dim(Im(T))=1 and therefore there is no such linear transformation

Is this poof valid?

Comment: No. Your calculation with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ proved that the two elements spanning the kernel are linearly independent. Therefore $\dim \ker(T)=2$, and there is no contradiction with rank-nullity.

Comment: BTW, does $\Bbb{R}_2[x]$ mean the vector space of at most quadratic polynomials with real coefficients? I don't think this notation is in universal use, so it is best to explain this. Easy enough to guess, I suppose, but it is a good idea not to make would-be-helpers waste time with such things :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, I thought it's a universal sign.

Comment: No problem with notation. But with those two polynomials now known to be linearly independent you can take advantage and extend that linearly independent duo to a basis of $\Bbb{R}_2[x]$. Then use the fact that you can freely choose the images of basis elements, and still get a linear transformation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a vectors pace, $\mathbb{R}_2[x] \cong \mathbb{R}^3$, so we can reduce the problem to there.

Consider the general question of whether there is a linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that the kernel is a specific two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the image of a specific one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I claim that the solution to any one problem of this form gives a solution to *all* problems of this form. By a change of basis, all "two-dimensional kernel one-dimensional image" problems are really the same problem.

(try figuring it out on your own before reading on)

By a change of basis -- i.e. an invertible linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ -- we can always convert any $m$-dimensional subspace into any other $m$-dimensional subspace. We need a different change of basis transformation for each one, but that's fine.

Suppose $S$ is *any* matrix with a two-dimensional kernel and one-dimensional image. Let $B_0$ be any change of basis that maps the space we want to be $\ker(T)$ to $\ker(S)$, and let $B_1$ be one that maps $im(T)$ to $im(S)$.

Putting all of this data into a diagram:

$$\begin{matrix}\mathbb{R}^3 &\xrightarrow{T}& \mathbb{R}^3
\\\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!B_0 \downarrow& & \downarrow B_1 \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\\\mathbb{R}^3 &\xrightarrow{S}& \mathbb{R}^3
\\\end{matrix}$$

That is, $B_1 T = S B_0$, and thus $T = B_1^{-1} S B_0$ will have the desired spaces as kernel and image.

So if you can solve *any* instance of the "two-dimensional kernel one-dimensional image" problem and find the two needed change-of-basis transformations, you can find $T$.

Comment: So because I can choose from infinite number of basis, and there is no contradiction with rank-nullity, there is a T like that?

Answer (score 1):

Since $1+x-x^2$ and $2+3x^2$ are linearly independent, as you have shown, you just have to choose any vector in $\mathbf{R}_{2}[x]$ which is not in the span of these two vectors, such as $-3+5x+2x^2$, and then

define $T$ by

$T(1+x-x^2)=(0,0,0)$,

$T(2+3x^2)=(0,0,0)$, and

$T(-3+5x+2x^2)=(0,0,9)$.

(I found the vector $-3+5x+2x^2$  by reducing the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&-1&0\\2&0&3&0\end{bmatrix}$.)

Comment: nice idea, but this way does not help in finding T

Comment: It defines $T$ on a basis of $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$, and therefore on all of $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$; so it shows that such a linear transformation exists.

Comment: So the last vector you choose forms a basis? $(-x+5x+2x^2)$

Comment: The 3 vectors together form a basis, since the first 2 are linearly independent (as you showed), and the 3rd vector was chosen not to be in the span of the first two.